# Dynamically accessing object names in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, concatenation

I'm writing a calendar in AS3.
I'm having a problem when I try access the object(days of the month) names.
Code below:

```
var tempDayName:String = "day"+dd.toString();
Calendar.tempDayName.gotoAndStop(2);
```

So this happens from 1 - 31 for each day of the month. "dd" is and int from 1 - 31.
Manually it works:

`Calendar.day1.gotoAndStop(2);`

But I want to put it in a for loop.

**Any help please?**

Best Regards
Luben

**--EDIT--**

The same does NOT work for Dynamic text does not work...

NewsMC["News"+1].text = NewsLoadedData[0].articleText;

Does anybody have any idea how to do the following:

NewsMC.News1.text = NewsLoadedData[0].articleText; NewsMC.News2.text = NewsLoadedData[1].articleText;

Cheers Luben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actionscript object are also arrays

you can test this Calendar["day" + i].gotoAndStop(2);

Comment: To clarify: Calendar.day1 is the same as Calendar["day" + 1]

Comment: HOWEVER!!!

The same does not work for Dynamic text does not work...

NewsMC["News"+1].text = NewsLoadedData[0].articleText;


NewsMC.News1.text = NewsLoadedData[0].articleText;
NewsMC.News2.text = NewsLoadedData[1].articleText;